# Compound nouns vs possessive (of)

Tags: possessives, compounds

Which should I choose: `The factory roof` or `the roof of the factory`?

Are there some grammar/rules about the difference? What case should I use the first sentence in? What case should I use the second sentence in?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I've been looking for a duplicate I feel has better answers. Though there is one guideline given, familiarity breeds idiomaticity in this area. //  I'd say one guideline is that the of-possessive generally sounds more prestigious rather than more formal (Lord of the Rings, not Ring Lord. And certainly not Fly Lord.) Another, far more general guideline is 'avoid anything sounding barbarous', as Orwell stated. Another is that cadence may play a part; I'd choose 'factory roof' in some situations, 'the roof of the factory' in others. Another is conciseness. Perhaps we need another answer.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth thank you